# An array of array of bytes in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, arrays

I need an array and each item in the array is an array of bytes like this, but I'm not sure how to do the:

```
Dim xx as array

xx(0) *as byte* = {&H12, &HFF}

xx(1) *as byte* = {&H45, &HFE}
```

Comment: Just a note that this is almost always a bad idea.  Byte arrays have their place, but by the time you start thinking about an array of byte arrays you should really think about a _collection_ of byte arrays instead.  Use something like a List<Byte()>.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can make a nested or "jagged" byte array like this:

```
Dim myBytes(6)() As Byte
```

This will create an empty array of 6 byte arrays.  Each element in the outer array will be `Nothing` until you assign an array to it, like this:

```
 myBytes(0) = New Byte() { &H12, &Hff }
```

However, it would probably be a better idea to make a `List` of byte arrays, like this:

```
Dim myBytes As New List(Of Byte())
```

This will create an empty list of byte array, which will stay empty until you put some byte arrays into it, like this:

```
myBytes.Add(New Byte() { &H12, &Hff })
```

Unlike the nested array, a `List(Of Byte())` will automatically expand to hold as many byte arrays as you put into it.

For more specific advice, please tell us what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to [this MSDN topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2de1t93(VS.80).aspx) for more details.

Here's the code to define a multidimensional array:

```
Dim lotsaBytes(2,4) As Byte
```

And to initialize it:

```
Dim lotsaBytes(,) As Byte = New Byte(2, 4) {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem with the following VB.NET example. Just drag and drop one button and one textbox. The code will be as follows inside the button click event:

```
Private Sub btnCalcBcc_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalcBcc.Click
        Dim BCC As Int16
        Dim Bcc2 As Int16
        Dim arr() As Byte = {&H1B, &H58, &H41, &H42, &H43, &H44, &H45, &H46, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H17, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H0}

        For i As Integer = 0 To arr.Length - 1
            BCC = BCC Xor arr(i)
            BCC = BCC << 1
            Bcc2 = (BCC >> 8)
            Bcc2 = Bcc2 And &H1
            BCC = BCC + Bcc2
        Next
        txtBCC.Text = BCC
End Sub
```

Comment: It's better to let people give you feedback in public here on Stack Overflow, so everyone can benefit, than privately to you via email.