# How to create Array of String Arrays

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string

I need to create an array of string arrays. 
Example:

```
> Array(0) = {"1", "a", "e"} 

> Array(1) = {"word", "at", "war"} 

> ...
```

I did:

```
Dim array()() As String

For i = 0 to 10
    array(i) = New String() {"dfdd", "dda", "aa", "bnb", "3", "ghj", "ht"}
Next i
```

But it fails with the exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You are initializing the child elements with `New String() {...}` inside the loop, but the "parent" array is not initialized.

Comment: That's what Im trying to know :S, Because If I try: Dim array()() As String = New String() it gives to me error. I dont know how to declarate this kind of arrays without creating and structure or a class

Comment: If you really want to use arrays: `Dim array As String()() = New String(10)() {}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the first dimension of your array was not initialized.

```
    Dim array(10)() As String

    For i = 0 To 10
        array(i) = New String() {"dfdd", "dda", "aa", "bnb", "3", "ghj", "ht"}
    Next I
```

I would suggest you look at List and maybe create a class instead if each string determine a different property.

Answer (score 3):

I think that a `List(Of String())` would suit your needs better here:

```
Dim arrays as New List(Of String())

For i = 0 to 10
    arrays.Add(New String() {"dfdd", "dda", "aa", "bnb", "3", "ghj", "ht"})
Next i
```

A List will automatically expand to hold as many arrays as you need. Then, if you still want an array of arrays, you can always do:

```
arrays.ToArray()
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Yp493S). Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1987301/3191599) to a similar question about byte arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do it this way:

```
Dim array = Enumerable _
    .Range(0, 10) _
    .Select(Function (n) New String() {"dfdd", "dda", "aa", "bnb", "3", "ghj", "ht"}) _
    .ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function ArrayToSV(ByVal array() As Object, ByVal seperator As Char) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim tmpstr As String
    tmpstr = CStr(array(LBound(array)))
    For i = LBound(array) + 1 To UBound(array)
        tmpstr = tmpstr & seperator & CStr(array(i))
    Next
    Return tmpstr
End Function
```

This method will give you the desired result, provide a Object Array and Separator it will return a string.